# ajax laravel добавить в таблицу

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

есть скрипт

```
$(".profile-form-teacher .input__button").click(function(){
        var userto = $(this).closest(".profile-form-teacher").find("#user-select").val();
        var replay = $(this).closest(".profile-form-teacher").find("#messaging-widget-textarea").val();
        var token = $(this).closest(".profile-form-teacher").find("input[type=hidden]").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/profile/dialog/send',
            data: {
                'userfrom': userto,
                'replaytext': replay,
                '_token': token,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // Вывод текста результата отправки
                $('#msg').html(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
                $('#msg').html(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

создал роут

```
Route::post('/profile/dialog/send', 'DialogController@send');
```

и контроллер

```
 public function send(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }


userto - получатель
replay - сообщение
```

как в контроллере вставить запись от текущего пользователя, не мне знаю как вставить id текущего пользователя

таблица :

```
from | to | replay
```

Comment: Если тебе нужно получить id авторизированного пользователя, то так `Auth::user()->id`

Answer (score 0):

Dialog - ваша модель

```
Dialog::create([
    'from' => Auth::user()->id,
    'to' => $request->get('userto'),
    'replay' => $request->get('replay')
]);
```

Но еще нужно отвалидировать все поля на корректность. И в ajax передавать csrf токен, иначе запрос не пройдет.

Comment: не понял про модель

Comment: @Aslero для каждой таблицы нужно создавать класс-модель, и уже обращаться к этому классу для работы с таблицей. Прочитайте про Eloquent

Comment: у меня в котнроллере нужно дописывать модель?

Comment: public function send(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }

Comment: я этом контроллере я вывожу данные через ajax

Comment: array:3 [▼
  "userfrom" => "1"
  "replaytext" => "asdasdasd"
  "_token" => "2Usp06xXtnxgLlE4MxTvFospyWobHmBPjbKUagTN"
]

Comment: все, понял, я лох))) а как добавить в связные таблицы, то есть есть таблица Dialogs где хранятся id пользователей переписки и таблица DialogsMessages где сама переписка и связь 1 ко многим

Comment: @Aslero https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships#om

Comment: получается в одном контроллере два запроса сделать?
$roles = Dialog::find(1)->orderBy('name')->get();
$roles = Dialog::find(1)->message()->orderBy('name')->get();

Comment: @Aslero нет, почему, вы создаете в Dialog связь с DialodMessages типа такого:
public function dialogMessages() {
return $this->hasMany('App\Models/DialogMessages', 'dialog_id');
}
а в контроллере $dialog = Dialog::where('from', Auth::user()->id)->where('to', $to)->with(['dialogMessages'])->get();
а потом выводите сообщения так:
foreach($dialog->dialogMessages as $message){
   //
}

Comment: суть такая, я проверяю есть ли диалог у меня и второго пользователя в таблице Dialog если нет создаю и сразу содаю запись в таблице DialogMessages и запихиваю туда сообщения

Comment: @Aslero https://pastecode.xyz/view/ad915e5e